# Sync Alt and Title values from CCK imagefields with media module file fields

Tags: 7, files, media

I have a situation where I really need to access the alt and title values of an image on a node.  I can retrieve these values in a node View, but in a file View these values are not accessible as they are not related the file.

I would like to, after adding an 'alt' and 'title' field to the 'image' file type in the media module, be able to sync the values from a node image field to the file fields.

Anyone know of way to currently do this?  Any suggestions?